# Select Menu JSF to CDI differences

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I want to use the arquillian warp test framework for a JSF project I am developing. I understand that I need to use the CDI annotations instead of the JSF ones to get this to work. I am using `@ViewScoped` beans so I have included seam-faces in my project to deal with this (i am running on JBoss 7). I have modified my beans to use `@Named` and where I was using `@PostConstruct` I have put this into the constructor which all seems to be okay.

When I access a view with a `selectOneMenu` it never has any list items. Here is the code form the view and the bean.

View:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ngoBean.ngo.country}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{ngoBean.countryValues}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
import com.a.Facade;
import com.a.CountryEnum;
import com.a.GoverningBody;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 */
@Named("ngoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class NgoBean implements Serializable {

    private GoverningBody ngo = new GoverningBody();
    private List<GoverningBody> ngoList;
    private boolean edit;

    private List<SelectItem> countryValues;

    @EJB(beanName = "NgoFacadeImpl")
    private Facade<GoverningBody> ngoController;

    public NgoBean(){
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //TODO this is a bad way of loading db data i should change it
        ngoList = ngoController.findAll();

        countryValues = initCountryValues();
    }

    public void add(){
        ngoList.add(ngoController.save(ngo));

        //reset the variable
        ngo = new GoverningBody();
    }

    public void edit(GoverningBody item) {
        this.ngo = item;
        edit = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        ngo = ngoController.update(ngo);
        edit = false;
    }

    public void delete(GoverningBody item) {
        ngoController.delete(item);
        ngoList.remove(item);
    }

    public List<GoverningBody> getNgoList() {
        return ngoList;
    }

    public GoverningBody getNgo() {
        return ngo;
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getCountryValues() {
        return countryValues;
    }

    public void setCountryValues(List<SelectItem> countryValues) {
        this.countryValues = countryValues;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> initCountryValues() {
        List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<>(CountryEnum.values().length);
        int i = 0;
        for(CountryEnum g: CountryEnum.values()) {
            items.add(new SelectItem(g, g.getName()));
        }

        System.out.println("items = " + items);
        return items;
    }
}
```

I tried annotating the method with `@Factory("countryValues")` but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: I have also fiddled around with the return types of the getCountryValues method

Comment: Why have you done away with the `@PostConstruct`? CDI fully supports it. It's generally a bad idea to do any processing in a getter: JSF frowns on this (it throws a validation error for inconsistent model state during request processing) and it's generally bad practice.

Comment: your right, i realised afterwards that it wasn't just a jsf annotation so I have reverted that change, I have moved the processing into an init method and created a variable for the values.

Comment: And you're still experiencing the same issue?

Comment: yes, still same issue, i'm thinking maybe there is something else i'm missing. I will edit and put the whole bean

Comment: :| I don't think you can mix `JSF` and `CDI` bean annotation like that. If you want to use `@ViewScope`, mark it as `@ManagedBean`. Besides, did you forget to initialize your `CountryEnum` object? In your `@PostConstruct` method, you initialize the `ngoList` and you didn't use it in your `initCountryValues` method.

Comment: oh ok, i though the [seam-faces](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/reference/snapshot/en-US/html_single/) allowed me to mix jsf scope annotations with CDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was unrelated to the symptom. The root cause of the problem was an incorrectly located `beans.xml` this should have be in the WEB-INF directory of the war not the META-INF directory of the ear.

I also changed the `seam-faces` dependency to use apache CODI, this is not necessary but this uses `@ViewAccessScoped` instead of `@ViewScoped` the different name is less ambiguous I think.

Comment: CODI supports @ViewScoped as well. ViewAccessScoped is a different scope.